# Obtain scaled predictor values when using `lm` in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

I'm using `lm` in R to do simple multilinear regression. Here's an example model:

```
m <- lm(formula = t ~ a + b + 0, data = df1)
```

where `t`, `a` and `b` are columns in `df1`. This model calculates 2 coefficients, let's call them `a.coef` and `b.coef`. If I then use this model to predict some other data, say in `df2`, I can get the predicted values like so:

```
predict(m, df2)
```

if I have the columns `a` and `b` in `df2` as well. It essentially returns

```
df2$a * a.coef + df2$b * b.coef
```

What I'd like, however, are the columns `df2$a * a.coef` and `df2$b * b.coef`. R sums them and gives me the answer, but I'd like to see how the scaling affects these values.

Is there a convenient way to do this in R (esp in `lm` or `predict.lm`), or will I have to manually code this myself? I played with the `terms` argument in `predict.lm`, but I couldn't get anywhere.

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**
I wrote this function:

```
scaled.fn <- function(dt, x, y, i) {
    # dt is data.table
    # x is dependent column (col name as str) 
    # y are predictor columns (col names as vector of str)
    # i is name of column to multiply, as str

    dep = paste(y, collapse = " + ")
    my.formula = paste(x, " ~ ", dep, sep = "")

    m = lm(formula = my.formula, data = dt)

    # column names in dt are named in y
    return(dt[, get(i) * coef(m)[i]])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sweep(df2, MARGIN = 2, coef(m), '*')
```

EDIT: more specific solution:

```
sweep(df2[,c("a","b")], MARGIN = 2, coef(m), '*')
```

Comment: Hmm...didn't seem to multiply the columns correctly though. Don't know why, because from the documentation it seems like this is what sweep is meant to do. In the meantime I've written my own function.

Comment: I was thinking whether I understood you right. So my solution works only if both df1 and df2 have only those two columns and in the same order. Check out my edit for more specific solution.